# Receive Gmail push notification only when a new message arrives

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to make an app that will find out if the recipient already replied to my email using GMAIL's push notification.
It is working well, but the problem is, I am receiving notification for any changes on my gmail.

Here is the code I used

```
request = {
        'labelIds': ['UNREAD'],
        'topicName': topic,
        'labelFilterAction': 'include'
    }
service.users().watch(userId=user.google_id, body=request).execute()
```

then i tried using the 'labelFilterAction': 'exclude'

```
system_labels = ['CATEGORY_UPDATES', 'UNREAD', 'DRAFT', 'CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS', 'INBOX', 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL', 'CATEGORY_PERSONAL', 'CATEGORY_FORUMS', 'TRASH', 'CHAT', 'IMPORTANT', 'SENT', 'STARRED', 'SPAM']
system_labels.remove('UNREAD')
request = {
        'labelIds': system_labels,
        'topicName': topic,
        'labelFilterAction': 'exclude'
    }
service.users().watch(userId=user.google_id, body=request).execute()
```

with this one, I am not receiving any notification at all.
any suggestion?

Comment: New, unread messages has the `INBOX`-label as well, so I think that all new messages will be excluded. Try `system_labels.remove('INBOX')` as well, and you will at least filter out a lot of messages, but maybe not all.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I still am not receiving any notification.

Comment: Hmm... Try `system_labels.remove('INBOX')`, `system_labels.remove('UNREAD')` and `system_labels.remove('CATEGORY_PERSONAL')`. I think that's it! :)

Comment: @khulas15 Did you manage to only be notified for the changes in `UNREAD`?

Answer (score -1):

working python code

```
credentials = get_credentials(email)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    request = {
        'labelIds': ['CATEGORY_PERSONAL'],
        'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/getNotification',
        'labelFilterAction': 'exclude'
    }
service.users().watch(userId='me',body=request).execute()
```

Comment: FYI this does not work, the API does not effectively filter labels, including system labels (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759803). The above code will receive notifications for UNREAD every-time an email is clicked on, hence you will see at least two notifications, AND you won't get any notifications for CATEGORY_PERSONAL. The docs are wrong (read the google issue tracker)